# What could be causing half of my Go packages to appear red in Goland after upgrading to version 1.20?

Tags: go, goland

There was Go 1.17, deleted, installed 1.20 using homebrew. prescribed ways. But in Goland half of the language package is red, respectively, and in my project half is red... but it compiles without errors and works. Tell me what could be the matter? PS: on the mac. goland version 22.1.4

Reinstalled GO by means of Goland, did not help, tried other versions of Go (18 \19) a similar situation. Changed with my hands in go.mod, changed with, go mod edit -go 1.20 - the same situation...

Comment: Update GoLand to 2023.1.4. It should help since it supports new `unix` build tag. Or add `unix` to Preferences | Go | Build Tags | Custom tags.

Comment: I updated the IDE and everything became good! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may not have updated the gopath configuration for goland.
You can check the following. In the goland editor
**file|set up|go|gopath(Is the Check global gopath 1.20)**
It is best to include pictures when asking questions.